# hls in html5 not working in android chrome browser

Tags: android, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I am getting issue in while playing video in "Android Phone's chrome Browser".

In that I am putting HTML5 video tag and providing m3u8 file's link as a source of video tag.
But it does not play in "Android's chrome browser".

But if I provide same m3u8 file's link to browser than it plays the video in Android's video player.

So what should be done to play video in HTML5 video tag?

**Note: I have checked this with Android 4.0.3 and 4.1**

Thanking in Advance,

Sagar Joshi

Comment: this: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/#asset=//storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one/dash.mpd;lang=en-US seems to work OK these days, maybe 5.0+?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the encoding, by looking at the server logs the playlists are requested, but since no webm content is found nothing is played.

That's really unfortunate because the stock browser used to play h264 videos just fine.

Answer (score 1):

the hls link will not work directly on android chrome you need a hls javascript library to get it to work, have a look at this code

```
<video id="my-video" style="width:640px height:480px;" controls>
                            <source src="{put your source link here}">
                        </video>
                    </div>
<script src="http://hlsbook.net/wp-content/examples/hls.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if ( Hls.isSupported() ) {
    var video = document.getElementById('my-video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('{put your source link here}');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
      video.play();
    });
  }
</script>
```

and remember the source link will not work on android platform, it works for ios-safari platform only as ios-safari platform don't require hls javascript, since Safari mobile does not support media source extensions and thus will not work with hls.js.
So for android you need to add the video link in the script tag in hls.loadSource and it will work on android chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using video.js's VHS to solve this https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming.

In my case, I was using fragmented MP4s which isn't supported by Android's native HLS support. To workaround this, you need to force VHS to override native support:

```
<video id="player" class="video-js" width="360" height="640" controls playsinline muted preload="auto" poster="https://example.com/poster.jpg">
  <source src="https://example.com/stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const player = videojs('player');
  player.play({
    overrideNative: true // <-- this fixes Android Chrome
  });
</script>
```

I was using hls.js before but had several issues with fragments MP4s. Definitely recommend video.js/VHS.